# Format output in sybase IQ 15.3

Tags: formatting, sybase

I am new to sybase and I am looking for some help formatting output. I have a query that I am running and output the results to a flat file.

Here is my command line:

```
isql -U ro -S DCIQ -P Qx346788 -imysql.sql -oresults.txt -b -w2500 -s"|"
```

The output of my query comes as:

```
|     20110915|        1.07000000|   27875450|UBC      |XW01     |
```

This is not what I am expecting. I want to format the output so that it is separated by pipe without the spaces. for example, I want this output:

```
|20110915|1.07000000|27875450|UBC|XW01|
```

How can I get get rid of spaces to get his output?

I tried other alternative but got error:

```
1> select "hi" from dummy;
2> OUTPUT TO data.txt
3> go
Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'OUTPUT' on line 2
```

Sybase IQ/15.3.0.6056/110506/P/GA/Enterprise Linux64 - x86_64 - 2.6.9-67.0.4.EL

Comment: The syntax in your alternative is incorrect.  Remove semicolon, remove line 2, and add ` > data.txt ` to the line with `go`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you may be able to do this.

1 - [Output redirect](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1510/html/iqapgv1/Redirec.htm) or use `temp_extract_*` options to setup a [temporary extraction point](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1510/html/iqapgv1/BABIBIGH.htm).  This causes the result set of a query to be written directly to a file, instead of going to the client.

2 - use `bcp`.  This does require the result set be accessible in a temporary table or a view, but it may allow you to extract the data and specify the delimiters you wish to use.

Comment: i cannot use bcp because i can only create temp table by session and bcp opens different session and wont see my data.  can you give me example of output redirect and how to pipe delimeted the data

Comment: To use your example `1> select "hi" from dummy`   `2> go > data.txt`  There are also examples in the documentation links.

Comment: hi, I try doing go > data.txt  but still see output with spaces  as described above

Comment: Then you will likely want to use the `temp_extract_*` options to try to get the output you desire.